# In Chrome user agent stylesheet, how does 2px = 0em?

Tags: css, google-chrome, stylesheet, margin, user-agent

I spent way too long trying to remove extra spacing to the left of a select box, when in Chrome Developer Tools, I finally saw that the user agent stylesheet was adding 2px margin-left (looking under the Computed Style). But when I click the margin-left dropdown to see where this style is being defined, it says it's being defined as 0em, as in the following screenshot...can someone explain this to me??

[image: Chrome user agent stylesheet - how does 2px = 0em?]

Comment: I can't recreate this, do you have a link to your site?

Comment: Zero, in CSS, is equal with all units. This is why you're allowed to have a unitless zero anywhere you have a size. There has to be some other CSS rule that you're missing.

Comment: I also have this issue - exactly the same problem and it is causing alignment issues everywhere. I can set the margin to 0, and that resolves it, but I shouldn't have to if the user agent stylesheet specifies 0 already.

Answer (score 2):

**I ran into this issue as well - setting an explicit height fixed the issue.**

The reason:

"*The purpose of intrinsic margins is to try to prevent adjacent controls from butting up against one another. Especially with rounded controls this looks terrible. The reason you see the values change is that we only set intrinsic margins when we think it won't disrupt the layout of the page. If the author specifies an explicit height/width on the control, then we assume the designer is needing pixel-precise control, and so we turn the margins off to avoid disrupting the page layout.

This feature was originally motivated by cases like Google's front page, which had two buttons that butted right up against one another. They have spacing now on the modern version of the page, but in the past they did not. This happens all over the place on the Web as well, especially with text fields next to buttons. They end up looking terrible on OS X especially (they look bad on Windows too, just not quite as bad).*"

Source: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128306

Answer (score 0):

From that screen shot, it looks like there is a rule like:
`margin: 2px 2px 4px 2px` that is overriding what the user agent originally spec'd as 0em